# Scrolling through a list with sublist in Ansible

Tags: list, ansible, yaml, sublist

I need to simultaneously traverse a data structure to align the values, I get this structure with the code below :

```
- name: Set instances
  set_fact:
    instance_db:
      - 'db2inst1'
      - 'db2inst2'

- name: Get Dialog Path
  shell: db2 get dbm cfg | grep -i "Current member resolved DIAGPATH" | awk {'print $6'}
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_flags: -i
  become_user: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ instance_db }}"
  register: kud_path

- name: set_fact
  set_fact:
    db2_store: "[{{ instance_db | list }}] + [{{ kud_path.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}]"
  vars:
    db2_store: []
```

**Result**

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "ansible_facts": {
        "db2_store": [
            "db2inst1",
            "db2inst2",
            [
                "/db2home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/",
                "/home/db2inst2/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Now I need to automatically traverse these indexes where I put `[*]`. Because as it is, I can only access the data like this `item[0][1]`

```
- name: Creating silent config
  template:
    src: template.txt.j2
    dest: '/tmp/template{{ item[0][*] | lower }}.txt'
    mode: '0775'
  loop:
    - "{{ db2_store }}"
```

This workaround was necessary to be able to pass both values to the template

**Template**

```
################## Database connection config ##################
INSTANCE={{ item[0][*] }}
DIAGLOG_PATH={{ item[1][*] }}db2diag.log
```

Any suggestions on how to do this or a more elegant way to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

```
instance_db = ["db2inst1", "db2inst2"]
kud_path.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list = ["/db2home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/", "/home/db2inst2/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/"]
```

Then you can use the `zip` filter which will pair the Nth element of the first list with the Nth element of the second list.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ instance_db | zip(kud_path.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list) }}"
```

Outputs:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "db2inst1",
            "/db2home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/"
        ],
        [
            "db2inst2",
            "/home/db2inst2/sqllib/db2dump/DIAG0000/"
        ]
    ]
}
```

This makes it easy for you to loop over:

```yaml
- name: Creating silent config
  template:
    src: template.txt.j2
    dest: '/tmp/template{{ item[0] | lower }}.txt'
    mode: '0775'
  loop: "{{ instance_db | zip(kud_path.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list) }}"
```

```
################## Database connection config ##################
INSTANCE={{ item[0] }}
DIAGLOG_PATH={{ item[1] }}db2diag.log
```

Comment: Your answer is fantastic, I didn't know the zip module, thank you for help